# How can I read \x1a from a file?

Tags: fread, utf

The contents of the file I need to read are as follows.

This file is in utf-16 LE format.

```
테스트갚켚테스트
```

in utf-16 LE

```
ff fe 4c d1 a4 cd b8 d2 1a ac 1a cf 4c d1 a4 cd b8 d2
```

I can't read the whole file because of \x1a. (갚, 켚)

How can I read it as a char?

Since it is used in flex, it must be read as a char.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
char str[1000];
fread(str, sizeof(str), 1, fp);
```

Comment: You can open in binary mode to prevent parsing the Ctrl+Z character as EOF.

Comment: Thank you!
That's what I was looking for.